# CDI @Alternative annotation with @ApplicationScoped

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have the following interface:

```
public interface StackConfigurationService {
    List<StackConfiguration> getStacksByAppId(String appId) throws ConfigurationException;
}
```

With two implementations:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class StackConfigurationServiceImpl implements StackConfigurationService {
    public List<StackConfiguration> getStacksByAppId(String appId) throws ConfigurationException { ... }
}
```

and

```
@Alternative
@ApplicationScoped
public class StackConfigurationMockService implements StackConfigurationService {
    public List<StackConfiguration> getStacksByAppId(String appId) throws ConfigurationException { ... }
}
```

The beans.xml contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <alternatives>
        <class>my.app.StackConfigurationMockService</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

However, CDI never uses the mock implementation of the service. Is the @ApplicationScoped annotation interfering in any way?

Comment: Can you post the full content of beans.xml file?

Comment: @LeoG. I updated the content of beans.xml

Comment: This should work. How is packaged your application? Check the location of the beans.xml (webapp/WEB-INF for a war, META-INF for a jar) and check also that StackConfigurationMockService is on the classpath.

Comment: Is it working when you remove the `@ApplicationScope`?

Comment: @Serban Not sure what CDI are you using, but try annotation your alternative with `@Priority` ( I think that's CDI 1.1+?)  in order to activate it. This is just another way to select your alternative (with slight difference). While it should work with beans.xml, this will verify that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Rouliboy the beans.xml is in the correct location (WEB-INF) and the mock service is on the classpath

Comment: @ujulu removing the annotation from both the implementation and the mock service didn't help. However, the implementation is still seen as a valid bean, even though it's not annotated any more. This doesn't seem right,

Comment: @Siliarus the Priority annotation is not recognised.

Comment: Isn't "bean-discovery-mode" attribute required since CDI 1.1?

Comment: @Ivo : it looks like he is using CDI 1.0 according to the beans.xml he posted. Event with CDI 1.1 it should work as he has annotated all his beans and bean-discovery-mode is annotated by default.

Comment: That proves that the scope is not the problem; can you post the injection point, I mean how you inject the bean.

Comment: I switched to CDI 1.1 and used bean-discovery-mode="annotated", but nothing changed. Removing bean annotations from classes (@ApplicationScoped) produces no errors, when it should.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was working all along. I was changing the settings in beans.xml, rebuilding and restarting the server, but the problem was in the browser. I was using the same tab and simply hitting refresh after each server restart. I assume the server cached the classes for that session. Opening in a new tab solved the problem.